# Is it possible to use dcast without variable column?

Tags: r, data.table

As I know, the standard way to use `dcast` function on object with class `data.table` is to specify variables (which will become column names) and values (which will become values of these columns).

I have a `data.table` with three columns - id, variable and value:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id = c(1, 2, 1),
                 variable = c("var_1", "var_1", "var_2"),
                 value = c(100, 200, 300))

dt

#>    id variable value
#> 1:  1    var_1   100
#> 2:  2    var_1   200
#> 3:  1    var_2   300
```

And I want this output provided by `dcast`:

```
dt_wide <- dcast(dt, id ~ variable, value.var = "value")

dt_wide
#>    id var_1 var_2
#> 1:  1   100   300
#> 2:  2   200    NA
```

But my question is - can I do this without specyfing variable? I.e. can I use `dcast` and get the output as above, having object as below?

```
dt[, variable := NULL]

dt
#>    id value
#> 1:  1   100
#> 2:  2   200
#> 3:  1   300

# dcast(dt)? Result:

data.table(id = c(1, 2),
           V1 = c(100, 200),
           V2 = c(300, NA))
#>    id  V1  V2
#> 1:  1 100 300
#> 2:  2 200  NA
```

I can imagine this is theoretically possible, algorithm could look like this:

1. Starting from top, take the first value from each id and put it into newly created column (choose name automatically).
2. Take the second value for each id - if nothing for some id, put `NA`.
3. And so on, until all values are taken.

I'm asking because I have the data only with `id` and `value` columns and want to perform this without additional computing (i.e. adding new column).

In my case `dcast` is really fast and I have found that addind new column is more computationaly expensive than performing `dcast` - so I would like to avoid this. Although maybe dcast is so fast because of use this `variable` column :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dcast`, we can create formula on the fly with an expression created with `paste` and `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(dt, id ~ paste0('var_', rowid(id)))
```

-output

```
   id var_1 var_2
1:  1   100   300
2:  2   200    NA
```